# Matrix field breaks backend Entries > 'page-name' page. "Endless" recursion error?

Tags: entries, matrix, admin

In backend Entries > 'page-name' I could only see the left nav side bar, and the top "header" bar (breadcrumbs + page name + save button), when ever there was a Matrix field on the page.
I noticed that the last line rendered (marked in blue) had a height of 0, so I started poking around in the CSS.

[image]

After disabling a `display: none;` (marked in green below) for the div immediately below the last div shown, I could see part of the page plus the error message shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

To me, it looks like some "endless" recursion error.

Does anyone have any idea on what might be going on here?

Thanks in advance for any light you might shed on this!

/Monkey

*Edit: added the top screenshot to show what the page looked like before I changed the CSS.*

Comment: I've been dealing with this this morning too. Even the simplest Matrix field causes this recursion error.

Comment: It's somewhat comforting to know that I'm not alone in this. <=) I hope we will have a solution to this soon!
I'm heading home now, so no more trouble shooting on my part until tomorrow morning. =/ I'll post if I've heard anything from support when I'm back at the office.

Comment: Yup, that solution worked for me.

Comment: Same here, see answer below. Cheers Brad! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brad was right, it was xDebug that was the culprit. So here's what I did:

1. In the Linux terminal I ran:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
   ```
2. In the xdebug.ini file I added the line below and saved.

   ```
   xdebug.max_nesting_level=256
   ```
3. In the Linux terminal I ran:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Done.

Note: if the this does not fix it, try changing the command in step 1 to:

```
sudo gedit /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

or just edit your *php.ini* file where ever it may be located.